# Add an expression template attribute or add an angular input attribute programmatically

Tags: angular, typescript

My goal is to add an input attribute to an programmatically created custom element.

```
<my-element [nameMe]='Foo'>
</my-element>
```

here I am trying to create the above element programmatically but getting error.

```
        const webCompInstance = document.createElement('my-element');
        //webCompInstance.setAttribute('[nameMe]', 'Foo');
```

Also, I would want to maintain the camelCase of the input attribute (e.g. nameMe is converted to nameme).

Thanks for your suggestions and solutions, in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When programmatically creating a custom element in Angular and setting an input property, you need to use the property name directly rather than the Angular binding syntax. Additionally, Angular automatically converts camelCase property names to kebab-case in the template, so you need to use the kebab-case version of the property when setting it programmatically.

Here's an example of how you can achieve this:

```
const webCompInstance = document.createElement('my-element');

// Set the input property directly (without Angular binding syntax)
webCompInstance['nameMe'] = 'Foo';

// Append the element to the DOM
document.body.appendChild(webCompInstance);
```

In this example, webCompInstance['nameMe'] directly sets the nameMe input property on the custom element. Angular will automatically convert the property name to kebab-case when rendering the template.

Remember to append the created element to the DOM or attach it to another element, so it becomes part of the document and Angular can detect and handle changes.

If you still want to use setAttribute for some reason, you can use kebab-case directly:

```
const webCompInstance = document.createElement('my-element');

// Use kebab-case for attribute name
webCompInstance.setAttribute('name-me', 'Foo');

// Append the element to the DOM
document.body.appendChild(webCompInstance);
```

However, it's more common and recommended to set properties directly when working with Angular elements.

Comment: That's a rare & insightful and answering all my questions. I will try the solution and update here shortly. Many thanks!!!